# Match regex pattern when not inside a set of quotes (text spans multiple lines)

Tags: c#, .net, regex

This is a continuation of my previous question [.NET regex engine returns no matches but I am expecting 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10013197).

My query is handling everything perfectly and I have my capture groups working great, however I have found a edge case that I do not know how to handle.

[Here is a test case](http://regexhero.net/tester/?id=42e224ce-d8c3-4faf-8b9d-2fa20997ff9d) that I am having trouble with.

```
INSERT INTO [Example] ( [CaseNumber] , [TestText] )
VALUES
(1 , 'Single Line Case'),
(2 , 'Multi
Line Case');
(3 , 'Two Lines with odd end '');
Case');
(4 , ''),
(5 , 'Case 3 is the Empty Text Case');
```

Here is my pattern I am using, I use the RegexOptions flags `Singleline`, `Multiline`, `ExplicitCapture`, and `IgnorePatternWhitespace`

```
^\(
((('(?<s>.*?)'(?!')) |
 (?<n>-?[\d\.]+)
 )(\s,\s)?
)+
#(?<!'')   #Commented Case 3 works, un-commented case 2 works
\)[;,]\r?$
```

I can either handle Case 3 or Case 4 but I am having trouble handling both.

If I had a way to check to see if there was a even number of `'` in the capture group 's` I could check then to see if we are on a real end of line or in text block that has a line that ends that just happens to match the pattern. but I can not figure out how to modify [other examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/668179/regex-to-match-a-string-with-an-even-number-of-quotes) to handle multiple lined text strings.

Can what I want be done with a single regex query or am I forced to do post processing (using the commented case) and do this is two passes?

---

Here is the code to run it in LINQPad

```
string text = 
@"INSERT INTO [Example] ( [CaseNumber] , [TestText] )
VALUES
(1 , 'Single Line Case'),
(2 , 'Multi
Line Case');
(3 , 'Two Lines with odd end '');
Case');
(4 , ''),
(5 , 'Case 3 is the Empty Text Case');
";

const string recordRegex =
@"^\(
((('(?<s>.*?)'(?!')) |
 (?<n>-?[\d\.]+)
 )(\s,\s)?
)+
#(?<!'')   #Commented Case 3 works, un-commented case 2 works
\)[;,]\r?$";

var records = Regex.Matches(text, recordRegex, RegexOptions.Singleline | RegexOptions.Multiline | RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace | RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture);
records.Dump();
```

Comment: What is the quoting syntax here? I don't see how `'foo''` is valid.

Comment: @Qtax You are correct but `'foo''\r\nbar'` is valid.

Comment: Ah yes, I didn't look much at the following line, syntax highlighting deceived me.

Comment: What's this `X'123'` syntax? Is that some special quoting in MS SQL? What does it mean?

Comment: @Qtax The location I am getting the text from is formatting binary values as `X'[0-9a-f]+'` instead of the normal `0x[0-9a-f]+` however since I don't need the `0x` or the `X'` I only capture the hex values. I meant to remove it from this example as it is not relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An expression like this would match such quotes:

```
(?:'[^']*')+
```

If you want to match `foo` when it's *not* inside such quotes, you could use something like:

```
foo(?=[^']*(?:'[^']*'[^']*)+\z)
```

---

> one match per line with the unquoted text and numbers as capture groups

Something like this:

```
(?xm)^
\(

(?:
    (?:
        (?<quote> (?:'[^']*')+ )
    |   (?<num>   -?\d+(?:\.\d+)? )
    |   (?<x>     X'[0-9a-f]*' )
    )
    (?:\s*,\s*)?
)+

\)
[;,] 
\r?$
```

Comment: I changed my final line of my pattern to `\)[;,](?=[^']*(?:'[^']*'[^']*)+\z)\r?$`. It now matches 3 & 4, but it now fails to capture 5.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain, I don't fully understand the question, what do you want that this expression does?

Comment: Follow the link I posted in my question to the regex hero site, it should have one match per line with the unquoted text and numbers as capture groups.