# matching a pattern that is not inside of quotes

Tags: c, regex, pcre

Can a pcre regex be created that will match only if the match is not inside quotes?  I have seen [regex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10032610) that use a positive lookahead to assert that there are an even number of `'` after the match and this almost works in my case except an uneven number of quotes may appear inside of `{` and `}`.

Example string: `a 'asdfasdfasdf' {' ' ' as'df'sdf}foo.bar 'asdf' { a' } asdf asdf foo.bar 'asdf' {a'} asdf'asdffoo.barasdf' 'foo.bar' asdf {'''}`

Is there some way to match foo.bar when it is not in quotes?

For my actual use case I have already constructed a parser to do this, but I first tried to solve it with a regex and was wondering whether there were some tricks I was missing.

Comment: Do the quotes have to immediately surround the match to be considered in the quotes - is asd'asdfoo.bar'sdjk a match?

Comment: A regex is the wrong tool for this. Just split the string on quotation marks manually, then use the regex on the odd-numbered pieces.

Comment: @CaptainMurphy - the foo.bar in `asd'asdfoo.bar'sdjk ` is not a match since it is in quotes.  @Raymond Chen - I agree with you and I've already implemented a proper solution; this question is more out of interest to see if a regex guru knows some features that I'm not aware of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it were just checking for the pattern occurring outside of quotes, then the solution is simple and you don't need to play games with lookahead. (Complex lookaheads are always a good way to produce pathologically slow regexen.) It's just as valid to know that there are an even number of quotes prior to the match as to know there are an even number of quotes following it, and the former is a lot easier and faster to check for, since it doesn't require matching the whole string speculatively on every potential match. You do need non-greedy repetition, though, or you'll find the last possible match instead of the first one.

Here's a simple example:

```
^(?:[^']*'[^']*')*?[^']*?foo\.bar
    |-paired 's|         |----------The pattern.
 |-shortest match-|
                   |----|
                   no quotes
```

But I think you actually also want to make `{}` special in some way. I'm just guessing, because you don't seem to be explicit about it. If the brackets can nest, then regexen are just not appropriate. ("Regexen can't count.")

Based on the updated requirements (in a comment) that

1. Quotes hide braces
2. Braces hide quotes
3. Both braces and quotes hide the target; and
4. Braces don't nest

the solution is not much different from the one I proposed above; we just add the `{[^}]*}` into the initial pattern. Here's one possibility:

```
^(?:[^'{]*(?:'[^']*'|{[^}]*}))*?[^'{]*?foo\.bar
```

Here's a (not very good) test; the -o option causes grep to show the matched portion, so you can see where each match ends:

```
$ grep -oP "^(?:[^'{]*(?:'[^']*'|{[^}]*}))*?[^'{]*?foo\.bar" <<\EOF
The target string is foo.bar and we should match the first foo.bar
'foo.bar' does not match but foo.bar does
Also, {foo.bar} doesn{'}t match, 'foo.bar' doesn{'}t match, {'foo.bar} doesn{'}t match, but foo.bar does
Note that {braces don't {nest so the end is here} and foo.bar matches}   
EOF
```

which produces:

```
The target string is foo.bar
'foo.bar' does not match but foo.bar
Also, {foo.bar} doesn{'}t match, 'foo.bar' doesn{'}t match, {'foo.bar} doesn{'}t match, but foo.bar
Note that {braces don't {nest so the end is here} and foo.bar
```

Comment: thanks for the reply.  What you are saying makes sense and looks like a better solution then using a lookahead for that case.  You are also correct that I wanted to handle `{}` specially.  If the `{}` are inside `'` then they are ignored, but, if they are outside quotes then any quotes inside of them should be ignored as there are allowed to be an odd number.  Does that make more sense?

Comment: @user1736516 It makes sense but: Do the brackets hide the target pattern as well as quotes, or can you recognize the target pattern inside brackets? And also, the most important: is a `{` phrase terminated by the first following `}`, or does it continue until the next *matching* `}`? In the latter case, no regex can do what you want.

Comment: yes, the brackets hide the pattern as well as the quotes.  If a `{` is inside of single quotes then it doesn't need to be terminated at all; otherwise, it is terminated by the first following `}`.

Comment: @user1736516: Ok, updated the answer. That about covers it, I think.