# Regular Expressions - a string containing an even number of a character among other characters

Tags: regex

I'm going through my homework and can't seem to figure out how to do this one.

Say the alphabet is `{a,b,c}`, we want a expression that finds strings with an even number of `c`s.

Example strings that are included:

```
empty set,
ccab
abcc
cabc
ababababcc
```

and so on.. just an even amount of c's.

Comment: can you write a regex to match a string with exactly 2 `c`s?

Comment: Duplicate of [Regex to match a string with an even number of quotes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/668179/regex-to-match-a-string-with-an-even-number-of-quotes), you just need to change "quote" to "c". Also, a regular expression is a poor choice of tool for this problem, since the resulting regular expression will be pretty much unreadable.

Comment: `(a+b)*(c(a+b)*)²)^N` should do it…

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex to allow only even # of `c` in input:

```
^(?=(([^c\n]*c){2})*[^\nc]*$)[abc]*$
```

#### [RegEx Demo](http://regex101.com/r/fL7aR8/2)

Comment: Couldn't the `[abc]*$` part at the end be dropped?

Comment: It can be dropped but I think OP wants inout to contain only `[abc]` characters.

Answer (score 0):

The below regex would match the strings which has only even number of `c`'s,

```
^(?:[^c]*c[^c]*c[^c\n]*)+?$
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/wN9yV5/1)

OR

```
^(?:[ab]*c[ab]*c[ab]*)+?$
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/wN9yV5/3)

Comment: @cs2016 it works for me. See the first demo. Please provide the input where the above regexes are not working..

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the total number of `c`'s count, not consecutive c`s - there is a nice theoretical approach, based on the fact that **a string with an even number of`c`s can be expressed as a finite state automaton with two states**.

The first state is the initial state, and it is also an accepting state. The second one is a rejecting state. Each `c` toggles us between the states. Other letters do nothing.

[image]

Now, you can convert this simple machine to regex using [one of the methods described here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/2016/how-to-convert-finite-automata-to-regular-expressions?newreg=235ca53877ce4177b62d3af1ce6bbfc3).

Answer (score 0):

Something like

```
^([^c]*(c[^c]*c)+)*[^c]*$
```

ought to do it. we can break it out, thus:

```
^          # - start-of-line, followed by
(          # - a group, consisting of
  [^c]*    #     - zero or more characters other than 'c', followed by
  (        #     - a group, consisting of
    c      #         - the literal character 'c', followed by
    [^c]*  #         - zero or more characters other than 'c', followed by
    c      #         - the literal character 'c'
  )+       #       repeated one or more times
)*         #   repeated zero or more times, followed by
[^c]*      # - a final sequence of zero or more characters other than 'c', followed by
$          # - end-of-line
```

One might note that something like the following C# method will likely perform better and be easier to understand:

```
public bool ContainsEvenNumberOfCharacters( this string s , char x )
{
  int cnt = 0 ;
  foreach( char c in s )
  {
    cnt += ( c == x ? 1 : 0 ) ;
  }
  bool isEven = 0 == (cnt&1) ; // it's even if the low-order bit is off.
  return isEven ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply

```
/^(([^c]*c[^c]*){2})*$/
```

In English:

> Zero or more strings, each of which contains exactly two instances of a c, preceded or followed by any number of non-c's.

This solution has the advantage that it is easily extendable to the case of a string with a number of c's which is multiple of 3, etc., and makes no assumptions about the alphabet.